# SSRS Count Record Based on Field Value (Status) in a Group

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-grouping, ssrs-expression

I have the data table below:

[--> Click here for the picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0Pwc.png)

I want to add new column and  count how times an employee is present in the office something like this:

[--> Click here for the picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1qku.png)

How can I count it in expression given that I have group in Employee.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use LookupSet() function to get the `In-Office` count. Add a tablix with the Employee Name group.

[image]

Note the Days Worked column is inside the Employee group scope but outside the details group scope.

Use this expression to get the count of Attendance In-Office per employee:

```
=LookupSet(Fields!Employee.Value & "-" & "In-Office",
  Fields!Employee.Value & "-" & Fields!Attendance.Value,
  Fields!Attendance.Value,"DataSetName"
 ).Length
```

Replace `DataSetName` by the actual name of your dataset. It will produce the below tablix:

[image]

---

**UPDATE:** Based on OP's comment.

Replace the `LookupSet` expression and use this instead to add multiple criteria to the filtered count.

```
=COUNT(IIF(Fields!Attendance.Value="In-Office" OR 
Fields!Attendance.Value="Out for Official Business",
Fields!Attendance.Value,Nothing))
```

It counts `In-Office` and `Out for Official Business` rows in the given group.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thank you alejandro zuleta. What if i gonna add new attendance status (out for official business) and i want it to be added in count, so the count will include "in-office" and "out for official business". would it possible?

Comment: it works. Thank you for your help.. it is very well appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via SQL script.

```
SELECT A.EMPLOYEE_NAME,A.DATE,A.ATTENDANCE,B.DAYS_WORKED 
FROM TABLE A
    LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT EMPLOYEE_NAME,COUNT(ATTENDANCE) DAYS_WORKED
        FROM (
            SELECT EMPLOYEE_NAME,DATE,ATTENDANCE 
            FROM TABLE
            WHERE ATTENDANCE = 'IN-OFFICE')
            ) B
    ON A.EMPLOYEE_NAME = B.EMPLOYEE_NAME
```

You now have the Field **DAYS_WORKED** then just add it to your table.

Comment: Thanks. but I am using fetch XML query as I am retrieving data in cloud server.

Comment: you should have added it to your post. and also to the tag. you included sql-server so I expected you use it as your back-end source.

Answer (score 0):

=Count(Fields!EmployeeName.Value,"DataSet1")

Comment: ssrs report in employee count calculation on experession =Count(Fields!EmployeeName.Value,"DataSet1")